# I do not have a iPod. I keep seeing iTunesHelper set to automatically launch

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes

I do not have a iPod. I keep seeing iTunesHelper set to automatically launch. This is some of what I see in Console. ( I dont want to share or use remote anything. "processName":"iTunesHelper","uptime":7999},"name":"comappleosanalyticsappUsage","uuid

Comment: You can probably disable it using launchctl, but it will have little to no impact on your system. Is there a reason you can’t have it running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTunesHelper uses little or no resources, so should not affect the operation of your Mac. IIRC, it is only used by iTunes to connect iPods and whatnot, and is not used for any other purpose.

Control over the launch of iTunesHelper at login used to be controlled from System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items tab:

[image]

If you see iTunesHelper in this list, select it, then click the minus [-] sign to remove it.

If you want to remove the app itself in iTunes 10.4 and later, it is found in the path `/Applications/iTunes/Contents/MacOS/` which you can get to by right-clicking in the iTunes app to show its contents.

In iTunes 10.3 and earlier, iTunesHelper is found in `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/`

Comment: Yes, that is where I keep removing it. So I do not have any control over it?

Comment: Are you removing the Login Item from Users & Groups, or deleting the app from the location inside the iTunes app itself?

Comment: I was only removing it from Users and Groups. I will delete it from the location in iTunes. Thank you!

Comment: So it was reappearing in Users & Groups. That's odd.